# Vue.js prevent re-render?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a template in Vue.js that looks like this:

```
<div class="filter">
    <div class="checkbox" v-for="(value, index) in range" :key="index">
        <span class="hotels">{{ count(index) }}</span>
    </div><!-- /.checkbox -->
</div><<!-- /.filter -->
```

The `count` method is important here. It triggers twice and also seems to be the cause of the second trigger and re-render.

This is my method:

```
count(value) {
    console.log('count');

    // Get the filtered AJAX data.
    let hotels = this.allHotels;

    const filters = Object.entries(this.filters);

    for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i += 1) {
        // Get the Object from the array(index 0 being the name).
        const filter = filters[i][1];

        // Break the v-model reference by creating a shallow copy.
        const values = filter.values.slice(0);

        // Merge any selected checkbox values with the one we are currently iterating.
        if (!values.includes(value)) values.push(Number(value));

        // Check if the current filter has selected checkboxes and filter if it does.
        hotels = filter.function(hotels, values);
    }

    return hotels.length;
}
```

Whenever I everything except the `console.log()` it works fine. Whenever I leave in the rest of the code the entire template seems to re-trigger. This seems strange because I am leaving the data in the template and the computed properties that the template relies on alone.

Is there any way to debug what is causing the second re-render?

**Entire component:**

https://gist.github.com/stephan-v/a5fd0b6bae854276666536da445bbf86

**Edit**

My components `count` function has a computed property in it called `allHotels`. This property is being set as a prop.

On the very first `console.log` it seems empty and then straight away it will get set causing the re-render. I was hoping that because this prop is coming from the backend it would take it as the initial value but this is not the case.

Is there anything to overcome this and prevent a re-render? There is no need for a re-render if Vue would take the prop data from the backend as initial data straight away.

Hopefully it is clear what I mean by this.

**Replication:**

Somehow I can't seem to replicate this, I would expect this to also work like my code and show an empty title on the first pass with a console.log:

https://jsfiddle.net/cckLd9te/123/

Perhaps because my prop data that I am passing into my component is a pretty big `json_encoded` block it takes time for Vue.js to interpret the data?

Comment: a re-render can only be tiggered if some part of that function changes data. The code you showed doesn't. Can you also share what those `filter.function` functions do?

Comment: The filter.function is supplied by a filter component: https://gist.github.com/stephan-v/fca52703bb41e5178e521400f6b6907b these filter components each add their filter functionality to a filterstack which will be run through each time a user clicks a checkbox to filter data. They manipulate data but simply accept data and return some filtered data.

Comment: Whenever I simply add `let hotels = this.allHotels;` to the component besides the `console.log()` it seems to already render twice. This seems to be the cause currently. This data is being supplied as a prop but on the first `log` it seems empty and then it gets set straight away. The prop data is coming from the backend. I guess Vue re-renders because of the prop but can't I have Vue simply see this as the initial value?

Comment: @LinusBorg I have edited my question since I figured out what is the cause. I am hoping there is a solution for this though. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What does "comping from the backend" mean? does the parent component get `allHotels` via AJAX from your API server? If that'S the case, the only solution is to not render the child component until the request to the API is finished.

Comment: It means the data is coming from a php controller and he prop data is simply being echoed out with php into a component prop. So the data is there straight away.

Comment: Okay. But still, I don't get the picture. in your gist, `allHotels` is a getter, not a prop. Where, when and how is this data added to the store?

Comment: @LinusBorg This is really way too much to be asking for on stackoverflow, so I am currently refactoring this into a generic `vue-search-filters` project for an easy demo. I will post back on stackoverflow if I still run into the same problem and I can showcase it properly.  Thanks for thinking along so far though. Appreciate it!